# Who sets the IsAuthenticated property of the HttpContext.User.Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, forms-authentication

This code is from the asp.net mvc RTM source code

Who sets the IsAuthenticated property of the HttpContext.User.Identity ?

```
   protected virtual bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext) {
        if (httpContext == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");
        }

        IPrincipal user = httpContext.User;
        if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Is the IsAuthenticated property set by calling the method (asp.net mvc 4.0 sample project):

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
```

When I debug the code of the **LogOn** method of the asp.net mvc 4.0 sample project after the above FormsAuth... method call. The execution of

```
User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

is still returning FALSE. Only when I debug the **LogOff** method the

```
User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

says TRUE. So who is setting this property to TRUE and WHEN ?

**UPDATE**:

This is about **FORMS** authentication!

I did now debug the LogOn method of the asp.net mvc sample project and after the LogOn action is returned my AuthorizeCore method I have overridden is called and then the IsAuthenticated property is TRUE!

Does setting of TRUE depend maybe of the ModelState.Value.Error collections ?

If count == 0 in the error collections the IsAuthenticated is TRUE
else the IsAuthenticated is FALSE

Can you confirm that?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This property is set by the forms authentication module by reading and parsing the forms authentication cookie from the **request**. I've put request in bold because I suspect that's the reason why you are observing this behavior. Let me explain. When you call `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` upon successful authentication you are adding the authentication cookie to the **response**. This cookie will be stored on the client browser and will be sent on **subsequent** requests. So it is only on subsequent requests that the user will be considered as authenticated. So you need to always redirect after calling the SetAuthCookie method. Inside the request that called this method you already know whether the user provided correct credentials so you don't need to check the IsAuthenticated property.

Comment: No source link but judging your other asp.net mvc solutions I found you are the expert ;-) I like above the explanation with the subsequent requests which many people did not understand/found googling for help in this same topic.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov If response is written the right cookie which include the FormAuthentication ticket after been authenticated successfully. The asp.net will read and resolve it from the request. it will determine if the `IsAuthenticated` true of false.  Any problem please correct me . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The origin of the property depends on the type of the `Identity`. For a `FormsIdentity`, the property just returns true:

```
/// <devdoc>
///    Indicates whether or not authentication took
///    place.
/// </devdoc> 
public  bool                         IsAuthenticated { get { return true;}}
```

That makes sense because the code in `FormsAuthenticationModule.cs` only assignes a `FormsIdentity` after authentication.  The code seems quite complex, I see it extracts a ticket from a cookie, but I can't find where it validates the ticket.

Comment: sorry Andomar I did not write its all about Forms auth. I edited my question.

Comment: What I have read so far in google and after some tests the FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie needs to be set that IsAuthenticated returns true. with var isAuthenticated = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext); in my overriden AuthorizeCore method. Actually it should be called AuthenticateCore but thats another story. I would be pleased and mark it as solution if anybody has a Microsoft link/proof whatever what makes the IsAuthenticated jump switch to true!