# Where does HttpApplication.User.Identity get updated?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, security

Seemingly duplicate question, but it wasnt answered in detail.
Well at least i dont believe it was.

[Who sets the IsAuthenticated property of the HttpContext.User.Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660539/who-sets-the-isauthenticated-property-of-the-httpcontext-user-identity)

The answer was

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie
```

But I decompiled System.Web.Security FormsAuthenication Class.
It Calls GetAuthCookie and adds it to the response.

Im Expecting its on the next request when the Session Cookie is found and not in FormsAuthentication as stated as "correct answer".
I searched the full decompiled source and didnt find a refernce to IPrincipal.
Does some really know ?
Can I trigger this process with and Event.?
I notice events such as

```
AuthenticateRequest
```

and  `AuthorizeRequest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's being set in event `AuthenticateRequest`, see `FormsAuthenticationModule.OnEnter` which is bound to `AuthenticateRequest` by `FormsAuthenticationModule.Init`. If want to override this identity, you can simply set `HttpContext.User` by yourself.

Comment: Thanks Lukas, thats what I was looking for  FormsAuthenticationModule. I will look into the direct access to HttpContext.User