# Why is User.Identity.IsAuthenticated always false?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm stugling with this "stupid" issue. I try to see if the user is authenticated in my action. I'm used to do like `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` but it always returns false. I look into the code of the `AuthorizeAttribute` and they use

```
protected virtual bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            //removed code...

            IPrincipal user = httpContext.User;
            if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return false;
            }

            //removed code....
        }
```

so my question and confusion is why won't this work in my action?

I use Simplemembership, this is the settings i use in `web.config`

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider">
              <providers>
                <clear />
                <add name="SimpleRoleProvider" 
                type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, 
                WebMatrix.WebData" />
              </providers>
            </roleManager>
            <membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
              <providers>
                <clear />
                <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" 
                type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, 
                WebMatrix.WebData" />
              </providers>
            </membership>
```

Im using default Login in template mvc4

```
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
            {                
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            return View(model);
        }
```

I use this in my authorizationattribute and it works, so my question is whats the difference?

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            //code here....

            if (httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                return true;

            return true;
        }
```

this is what i use in my action

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //removed code....

            if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return View();
            }

            // revmoved code...

            return View();
        }
```

Comment: That is hard to answer without knowing your authentication settings (probably set up in web.config)

Comment: The authentication cookie has not been set. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660539/who-sets-the-isauthenticated-property-of-the-httpcontext-user-identity

Comment: @Jasen, i don't see his login method to confirm if he set the authentication cookie or even uses cookies. what did you see?

Comment: Please share your login method

Comment: @Jasen look at my question i updated it. I'm just confused by why it works in the attribute without using cookies?

Comment: @Dejan.S when exactly is User.Identity.IsAuthenticated failing for you? Can you share your action where it is failing? WebSecurity is setting the auth cookie after successful login. When it does fail do you have the .ASPXAUTH cookie set on the browser?

Comment: @jasen, it fails in a just a regular action when i try to check if user is authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

I generally use the `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest` for this not a Filter.
Please feel free to ignore my `CustomPrincipal`, you don't have to do it that way. Just a quick paste from one of my projects.

I did not see your code for `FormsAuthentication` so difficult to say why `HttpContext.User` is not getting set up right. Please post your `FormsAuthentication` code.

```
 protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
            var serializeModel = (CustomPrincipalSerializeModel)
                                 JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString(authTicket.UserData,
                                                                      typeof (CustomPrincipalSerializeModel));

            var roles = serializeModel.Roles ?? new string[0];
            var newUser = new CustomPrincipal(authTicket.Name, roles)
                {
                    UserId = serializeModel.UserId,
                    UserName = serializeModel.UserName,
                    FirstName = serializeModel.FirstName,
                    LastName = serializeModel.LastName
                };
            HttpContext.Current.User = newUser;

        }
    }
```