# how to get isAuthenticated working in client mvc app ,in cross platform authentication and autherization(web api)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cross-domain, asp.net-web-api2, claims-based-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I am using mvc application and web api 2 with asp.net identity 2.
my client mvc application working with tokens,
it gives an api call on login submit button then web api service returns 
a token and user claim (i.e username)
my question are following:

1. how to use IsAuthenticated property in my mvc app as its always
   false.
2. how to give a remember me feature to my uses.
3. Is it necessary that my api would return userclaim-username and accesstoken and other data, can I get email and phone as user claims.

**Update:**

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            return View(model);
        }
        var responseDictionary = GetResponseAsDictionary(model.usename, model.password);
       return View(model);
    }
```

I am getting this response dictionary from web api

Now how can I set `IsAuthenticated`  by using this token from service?
I know how to do this in forms authentication but I have no idea how to do this using AccessTokens,
 and I would also like to persist this token across the user session in tempData or session.

Comment: I think you didn't really try to find out how the authentication magic works in MVC, you can start with:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660539/who-sets-the-isauthenticated-property-of-the-httpcontext-user-identity

Also please edit your question in a way it is readable, It's really hard to read at the moment. If you need some code hints, provide your current code or structure diagram

Comment: @mikus i updated the formatting and posted some code as you suggested.

Comment: I think you should really take 2min and check how your question was edited to current state by others, comparing to what you served us :P Now maybe somebody will actually spend time trying to solve it. My time quote on it is over,

Comment: i dont know how they edited it to current state ,i think they should post helping video.

Answer (score -1):

```
it was easy to do , i can use 
`
formsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie

` on Client app and i had to redirect the page after setting this cookie

1: Get the Authtoken from web api 
2: if it returns Access_token ,then you can set authcookie
3: finnaly you can use IsAuthenticated property on client App 

4: i would ask another question for how to do a remember me feature 
,as i dont know how to store token and is 
it safe to store as it is without further encripting it.
```

Comment: i really don't know how people format answers and questions here :P