# Why do I get User.Identity.IsAuthenticated false

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, membership-provider

I get my `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` in false. I think this is causing my second problem: I **cannot access** controllers with `[Authorize]` decorator.

My code goes:

- My `MembershipProvider`inheritance, with the implementation on `ValidateUser`:

  ```
  public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
  {
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
          return false;

      var user = DBManager.Context.Usuarios.First(x => x.Nombre == username);
      if (user.Pass != password)
          return false;
      return true;
  }
  ```
- My `Web.Config` authentication part:

  ```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" defaultUrl="~/" timeout="20" slidingExpiration="true" />
  </authentication>
  <membership defaultProvider="Membership">
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add name="Membership"
       type="SGKS.Security.Membership" />
    </providers>
  </membership>
  ```
- My `Contorller`:

  ```
  [HttpGet]
  [AllowAnonymous]
  public ActionResult Login()
  {
      if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
      {
          return RedirectToAction("Index", "Facutra");
      }
      return View();
  }

  [HttpPost]
  [AllowAnonymous]
  public ActionResult Login(Login model)
  {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
          if (System.Web.Security.Membership.ValidateUser(model.Nombre, model.Pass))
          {
              FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Nombre, model.Recordarme);
          }
          ViewBag.Error = "Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos.";
      }
      return View(model);
  }
  ```

Comment: Not related, but the code implies that you may be storing the password as plain text. Modern security practice calls for storing a salted & hashed password.

Comment: @eric-j  IKR, I'm just trying to use it, then I'll implement hashed...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Who sets the IsAuthenticated property of the HttpContext.User.Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660539/who-sets-the-isauthenticated-property-of-the-httpcontext-user-identity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8665163/181087):

> When you call `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` upon successful authentication you are adding the authentication cookie to the **response**. This cookie will be stored on the client browser and will be sent on **subsequent** requests. So it is only on **subsequent** requests that the user will be considered as authenticated. So you need to always redirect after calling the `SetAuthCookie` method.

In other words, you need to add `RedirectToAction` immediately after calling `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie`.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
// The ASP.NET framework automatically puts a returnUrl query string parameter of the original
// page the user requested. You just need to add that parameter here to gain access to it
// (assuming you want to redirect the user back to the original requested page rather than 
// some start page).
public ActionResult Login(Login model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (System.Web.Security.Membership.ValidateUser(model.Nombre, model.Pass))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Nombre, model.Recordarme);

            // Redirect so the next request can see the user as authenticated
            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        ViewBag.Error = "Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos.";
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked, but... HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized :(

Comment: User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is still false